# It works local with xampp. The login works live, but the register does not

Tags: php, mysql, networking, phpmyadmin

Everything works fine. 
The error log does not show a thing. 
Stripe tells me that it were created successfully. 
But i have no entry in my own database. 
On the other side the login works perfectly well. And the whole backend is working fine. Is there any known error or something i missed here?

```
  

       session_start();
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    require_once('Stripe');
    require_once('db.php');
    mysqli_set_charset($mysqli,"utf8");
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT ID, password FROM accounts WHERE email = ?')) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['email']);
        $stmt->execute(); 
        $stmt->store_result(); 
        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
            echo 'email exists, please choose another!
Back';
        } else {
            if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO accounts (email, password, customer) VALUES (?, ?, ?)')) {
                $customer =  \Stripe\Customer::create([
                    "email" => $_POST['email'],
                  ]);
                $uniqid = uniqid();
                $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
                $password = hash('sha512',$_POST['password']);
                $stmt->bind_param('sss',  $_POST['email'], $password, $customer->id );
                $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Try doing `if ( false===$stmt ) {
  die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));
}` and see whats the error.

Comment: wont be helping / didnt help. Bc as i said it runs through ( as if everything is correct and present) but the db entry wont work.

Comment: Where is ```$mysqli``` coming from? Is it actually initialized properly?

Comment: @paskl yes it is. Just as i said. The login works in live mode and its working locally.

Comment: Then maybe the database settings are different from live server?